# How to throw an exception in akka stream?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I would like to throw an exception as the following:

```
  Source.empty
      .map {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed")
      }
      .runWith(Sink.foreach(println))
      .onComplete {
        case Success(_) =>
          println()
        case Failure(e) =>
          println(s"Thrown ${e.getMessage}")
      }
```

But the exception does not appears in the `onComplete` method. It prints

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed
    at com.sweetsoft.App$.main(App.scala:30)
    at com.sweetsoft.App.main(App.scala)
```

How to throw an exception, that will stop the stream and appears at the end?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Akka has build in Error handling : [Akka Supervision Strategies](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/stream/stream-error.html#supervision-strategies)

```
val testSupervisionDecider: Supervision.Decider = {
        case ex: java.lang.RuntimeException =>
          println(s"some run time exception ${ex.getMessage}")
          Supervision.Stop
        case ex: Exception =>
          println("Exception occurred and stopping stream",
            ex)
          Supervision.Stop
      }
```

and you can use the supervision decider as

```
val list = List.range(1, 100)

  Source(list).map { item =>
    if ((item % 2) == 0) {
      throw new RuntimeException(s"$item")
    } else {
      item
    }
  }.withAttributes(ActorAttributes.supervisionStrategy(testSupervisionDecider))
    .runWith(Sink.foreach(println)).onComplete {
    case Success(_) =>
      println()
    case Failure(e) =>
      println(s"Thrown ${e.getMessage}")
  }
```